# Rollback feature

Tags: support

What does the rollback feature do exactly?

I am new to the site and have found a few options under the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60491) I have recently posted, so found this rollback option intriguing, hence wanted to know what it does.

Comment: Using this feature you can undo the edit made by joriki to your question. To see what exactly he did (he just added a missing blank space), [look here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/60491/revisions). To get to that page, click on edited xx time ago over joriki's name in the usual display of the question.

Comment: How would you use rollback? I know that you get the cleanup badge for performing your first rollback. How does that work?

Comment: @cuabanana First, you need 2000 points to be able to edit the posts by others. When you have them, the edit dialog will provide you with an option to roll the post back to an earlier version of it.

Comment: I completely misunderstood that feature D: ! I have several times used it on posts and thought it allowed one to see the version that was being corrected... Better to learn it now than never.

Comment: I voted to close this older question as duplicate of a newer, as the behavior change and this is outdated.

Answer (score 7):

Rollback reverts a post to the last revision by the original author.