# Why does the rollback link require so much reputation?

Tags: feature-request, editing, suggested-edits, privileges

I understand and agree with a high reputation cutoff for making auto-approved edits, and even that several people have to approve other edits ([So Much Approval Required For Edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/)). However, as a comment on  [Rollback feature](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/) says you cannot even *propose* a rollback without copying and pasting text from an older revision, although users with $\ge2000$ reputation have a rollback link.

Since it seems like unofficial rollbacks can be proposed by users without that privilege, **why can't they propose official ones?** As an aside, "Help Center > Privileges > Edit Questions And Answers" doesn't mention the rollback link specifically.

(In case that requirement is no longer the case, consider this a bug report, because I do not currently have rollback links.)

Comment: It's not a bug, as indicated at ["no rollback link"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149421/no-rollback-link) on Meta.SO